# How to avoid inconsistent Run-time error -2147188160 (80048240)?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

My code generates 4 PowerPoint files from an excel document where I've aggregated data from my main file. One by one, it cuts and pastes a section of the excel sheet onto an individual slide, replaces some filler words with the appropriate date, saves and closes.

My code works, however it SOMETIMES gets tripped up with a

> Run-time error -2147188160 (80048240)

a pasting error, which doesn't always happen in the same place. The remedy is always to exit my program and re-run it. The code executes in less than 10 seconds, so this is no big deal, just fair nuisance. Sometimes it takes 1 or 2 tries to get it to work.

Any advice on how to avoid these annoying run-time error trip ups?

```
Sub GeneratePowerPoints()

'For using powerpoint
Dim dummyfile As String
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim MySlide As Object
Dim MyShape As Object
'Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation

Dim j As Long, allhotels() As Variant, sourcerange As Range, sourcebook As String
Dim d As Date, e As Date, f As Date, lastmonth As String, twomonthsago As String, threemonthsago As String

'Get some month names
d = DateAdd("m", -1, Now)
e = DateAdd("m", -2, Now)
f = DateAdd("m", -3, Now)
lastmonth = Format(d, "mmmm")
twomonthsago = Format(e, "mmmm")
threemonthsago = Format(f, "mmmm")

sourcebook = "BT Strat Sheet.xlsm"
allhotels = Array("SBH", "WBOS", "WBW", "WCP")
dummyfile = "P:\BT\BT 2017\BT Strategy Meetings\2017\Hotel Strat Meeting Dummy File.pptx"

For j = 0 To 3

    Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPT.Visible = True
    PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:=dummyfile

    'SLIDE ONE
    Set sourcerange = Workbooks(sourcebook).Worksheets(allhotels(j)).Range("A2:J21")
    sourcerange.Copy
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
    Set MyShape = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Count)

    'Set size
    MyShape.Left = 152
    MyShape.Top = 152
    MyShape.Height = 500
    MyShape.Width = 650

    'SLIDE TWO
    Set sourcerange = Workbooks(sourcebook).Worksheets(allhotels(j)).Range("A73:J82")
    sourcerange.Copy
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
    Set MyShape = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.Count)

    'Set size
    MyShape.Left = 152
    MyShape.Top = 92
    MyShape.Height = 500
    MyShape.Width = 650

    'SLIDE TWO
    Set sourcerange = Workbooks(sourcebook).Worksheets(allhotels(j)).Range("A85:J94")
    sourcerange.Copy
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
    Set MyShape = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes.Count)

    'Set size
    MyShape.Left = 152
    MyShape.Top = 300
    MyShape.Height = 500
    MyShape.Width = 650

    'SLIDE THREE
    Set sourcerange = Workbooks(sourcebook).Worksheets(allhotels(j)).Range("A24:J43")
    sourcerange.Copy
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
    Set MyShape = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes.Count)

    'Set size
    MyShape.Left = 152
    MyShape.Top = 152
    MyShape.Height = 500
    MyShape.Width = 650

    'SLIDE FOUR
    Set sourcerange = Workbooks(sourcebook).Worksheets(allhotels(j)).Range("A54:J58")
    sourcerange.Copy
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
    Set MyShape = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes.Count)

    'Set size
    MyShape.Left = 152
    MyShape.Top = 152
    MyShape.Height = 500
    MyShape.Width = 650

    'SLIDE FOUR
    Set sourcerange = Workbooks(sourcebook).Worksheets(allhotels(j)).Range("A46:J50")
    sourcerange.Copy
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
    Set MyShape = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes.Count)

    'Set size
    MyShape.Left = 152
    MyShape.Top = 380
    MyShape.Height = 500
    MyShape.Width = 650

    'SLIDE FIVE
    Set sourcerange = Workbooks(sourcebook).Worksheets(allhotels(j)).Range("A61:J70")
    sourcerange.Copy
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
    Set MyShape = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes(PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes.Count)

    'Set size
    MyShape.Left = 152
    MyShape.Top = 152
    MyShape.Height = 500
    MyShape.Width = 650

    'Find and replace month placeholders
    'Straight boilerplate
    Dim sld As Slide, shp As PowerPoint.Shape, i As Long

    For Each sld In PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "LastMonth", lastmonth)
                End If
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld

    For Each sld In PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "TwoMonthsAgo", twomonthsago)
                End If
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld

    For Each sld In PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "ThreeMonthsAgo", threemonthsago)
                End If
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld

    'Save it
    PPT.ActivePresentation.SaveAs "P:\BT\BT File Drop-off Location\" & allhotels(j) & " " & lastmonth & " Strat Meeting.pptx"

    'Close it
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Close
Next j

'Exit PowerPoint
PPT.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: How about using your google-fu? If you stick the error code in google the literally first result answers your question.

Comment: @Banana Hi Banana. I did read a few posts about this specific error where the general consensus seems to be to add some `Application.Wait`s around in the code - I'm just a little displeased with that fix as it feels like more of a band-aid solution... Was wondering if there was something else I was missing that could make things smoother.